# What do the different shades of colors mean on an asset in the Chrome Devtools Timeline?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I cannot find a good legend on how to read the Chrome Devtools Performance Timeline.

I know that the different **colors** refer to the type of work is being done (`scripting`, `rendering`, etc).

But what I don't understand is, what to the different *shades* of those colors mean on the timeline?

[image]

I used to think they represented the amount of time was spent parsing/executing an asset vs. the amount of time it spends transferring it over the network, but that doesn't seem to be true, because the long asset in the photo above has this timing information:

```
Duration    552.30 ms (509.58 ms network transfer + 42.72 ms resource loading)
```

The dark yellow part of the asset is bigger than the light yellow one, but not 10x bigger.

Does it represent how much of the asset is executed? That doesn't make sense because the same color shading happens on the HTML document itself...

Comment: Devtools `Network` panel seems to use the same shading which means "Stalled" and "Content Download", see [timing explanation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.

Those shades correspond to whether the time is caused by the files "self" or the files "children":

[image]

I may be butchering this explanation, but "Self” refers to the length of time it takes for that specific file to load/execute, “children” references any additional files that get initiated by the parent, and the time they spend loading.

So it makes sense, in my original screenshot from the tweet, the “project-project” file is the file in our codebase that async loads other JS modules, so it makes sense that it would have a huge dark yellow section, since it is the one that initiates the requests for all those files.